# How to list related experience on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, cover-letter

I'm currently looking for a new job, and found one listing on Craigslist that I feel would be a perfect fit. However, some of the related domain knowledge (for software development) is out of scope on my resume.

My resume has the details of my two most recent jobs listed, and two older jobs are mentioned in passing, but not detailed to keep the resume to one page, otherwise it would be a page and a half.

Would it be better to included the third job in detail, and expand to the extra half page to show domain knowledge, or should I talk about it only in my cover letter and potentially wait for questions about it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a two page resume if it's relevant

Comment: @JoeStrazzere tech resumes are impossible to limit to one page.  The first page of mine just contains the technologies I've used.

Comment: @RichardU Actually, I firmly believe that a prospective employer *doesn't* need to know all 100+ technologies, tools and applications that I've worked with in my life. They just need to know the ones that are relevant to them. Having said that I agree that going over the single page limit is fine if you're adding useful information rather than irrelevant fluff.

Comment: @Cronax you'd be surprised, but what I do is I list my tech from most relevant to least relevant.  It's gotten me hired when there are some "nice to haves" they have in mind that didn't make it to the job listing.

Answer (score 5):

Put it in your resume under "additional experience" **AND** include it in your cover letter:

> As you will note in my attached resume I have experience in crafting widgets from a previous employer where I worked as a Widget crafter first class.

Put everything **RELEVANT** to the job you are applying in your resume.

Comment: +1 from me as well. For some reason people think a resume is a static thing, when the best results tend to come from tweaking it to suit the job you're applying for. Not by adding fake information, but by emphasising the things that you feel make you qualified for the job and de-emphasising or outright omitting stuff that's irrelevant.